# Kendo Cancel dropdownlist selectionChange event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I use Kendo-angular library. When user select an item in my dropdownlist, the selectionChange event is triggered and based on some conditions I want to cancel the change event and revert to previously selected value in the dropdownlist.

Can this be achieved with the kendo dropdownlist component ?

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
[data]="services" 
[textField]="'defaultLabel'" 
[valueField]="'id'" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedService"
placeholder="Select a service" 
(valueChange)="onServiceChanged($event)"> 
</kendo-dropdownlist>


 onServiceChanged(event) { }

//event is the actual selected value, not the event
```

Comment: check the event list on the documentation
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-events

public valueChange(value: any): void {
        this.log('valueChange', value);
    }

Comment: faced the same issue and unfortunately no way for now - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1285

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

```
    <kendo-dropdownlist #dropdown
        (valueChange)="valueChange($event, dropdown)">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>


valueChange(value,  dropDownControl: DropDownListComponent) {dropDownControl.writeValue("old value");}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the event list on the documentation
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-events

```
public valueChange(value: any): void {
// Your condition here
        this.log('valueChange', value);
}
```

Comment: I have checked the documentation and even if I use the valueChange event, I still don't know how to cancel the event.